# Reading input with varying number of ints each line in C++

Tags: c++, input

I am trying to read in user input from the console. The data is as such

```
3
3 100
5 100
6
9 200
6
9
```

Where the first line represents N, and there are 2*N entries following it. How would I decide whether a line has two int inputs or just one.

I thought about implementing getline, but that just gives me the whole line, and it gives me a string with a space in between.

Thanks

Comment: getline + stringstream.

Comment: Let's get basic here.  Why are some lines having two integers while other lines have only 1?  Answer this and your input becomes easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use `getline` and parse the string myself. This gives you the most flexibility and is pretty much a requirement when you get to the point that you want to do error handling.

It's not that hard to split a string into pieces based on a common delimiter (like a space). And writing that code is good practice for you.

```
std::vector<std::string> splitAt(const std::string &input, const std::string &delim) {
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    ...
    return vec;
}
```

Implement that, and you're golden. The rest of the problem solves itself, and you can use it over and over.